# Magento 2.3.1 Composer Fatal error installing anything

Tags: composer, fatal-error, magento2.3.0, magento2.3.1, data-migration-tool

After thing to install a few other extensions, I'm getting the Fatal error message with anything when using Composer.

I have installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.3.1 and I'm trying to install the data migration tool using the instructions on github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.1

I get

./composer.json has been updated

but then get the following error

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp1::initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code:69
Stack trace:

## 0 [internal function]: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp1->initModuleDeployment(Object(Composer\Script\Event))

## 1 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Script\Event))

## 2 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))

## 3 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(204): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('pre-update-cmd', true)

## 4 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(18 in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code on line 69

Have tried Magneto 2.3.0 & 2.3.1 and both get the same error.

Can someone point me int he right direction to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: have you run 
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.1  ?

Comment: Get the following using composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git github.com/magento/data-migration-tool 

[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
  No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of github.com/magento/dat
  a-migration-tool, could not load a package from it.